# ubuntu 13.10 performance for 1 GB machine

Tags: 13.10, system-installation, performance

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 to my desktop which has 1 GB main memory and AMD 64 bits CPU. It happens that the system freeze, applications not response sometimes and crashes a few times.

I just learn that 1 GB is minimum requirement for Ubuntu 64 bits. I just wonder if it is memory not enough that I better to increase to 2 GB to improve performance.

Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung

Comment: Do you have the necessary graphics drivers for your system? Unity is very finicky about that for all it's animations. Otherwise it will freeze every few frames.

Comment: I think 1GB of RAM is too low to comfortably run any modern OS, let alone the Unity 3D desktop. I would upgrade the RAM to 2GB at least and consider using Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. The minimum for 64bit Ubuntu is 768 MB of RAM memory.
2. Try increasing your swap memory.
3. I think you can use 32bit version, it would be better.

And one more tip: use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1GB of RAM and 64-bit architecture, then I would suggest two things:

1. Use a 32-bit version of Ubuntu
2. Use either Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Whatever you do, with such hardware configuration stay away from the resource-hungry Unity.

And lastly, add a sufficient dose of `swap`. Anything above 2GB should work fine.

See also:

- [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 0):

Couple points:

- increase swap
- use openbox or blackbox destktop environments as super-light-weight alternatives (my ram usage with it right now is around 700 MB , no flash running)
- limit startup scripts, processes, etc.
- Use a usb as RAM: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/115627/295286) or [here](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/07/add-virtual-ram-to-ubuntu-using-spare.html)