# How can i speed up my computer? or how can i deactivate the visual effects for better performance?

Tags: graphics

I need to speed up my computer. even when im opening workspace switcher, is lagging! the cpu usage is over 50% all the time and it increases to 100% with a simple mouse move.

Comment: So we are supposed to give any decent information without knowing  what your system specifications are? Or if you are using any 3rd party drivers? If you have a P2, P3 or P4 what you see is to be expected. If it is a new modern I3 I would expect something else to be the problem of this lag; not Unity. Please edit details into your question.

Comment: Sorry.. my mistake. . I got 1.4gb ram. 1.7ghz intel celeron single-core  and a gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128  bits.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get the correct hardware support for your GPU instead of
   burdening your CPU with graphics.

   - Look for hardware acceleration wherever you can find it and install
     all the opengl mesa etc. If using nvidia or other non intel, go to
     software center, click "edit" select "software sources" and click on
     the "additional drivers" tab. There you will see proprietary drivers
     if there are any available for your setup. Reboot for changes to take
     effect. The "tested" versions are usually the most stable.[For intel see here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.6-linux)
   - If you're using an older system, make sure you have enough swappiness
     and swap space to take the load off the system when it's needed.
     Also, many older systems benefit from the use of zram: [see this
     post](https://askubuntu.com/a/544250/167115)
2. Switch to a lighter desktop like Ubuntustudio Xubuntu or Lubuntu.
   All of these are designed for system performance through low
   overhead and minimal use of desktop effects.

[ubuntustudio.org](http://ubuntustudio.org/)

[xubuntu.org](http://xubuntu.org/)

[lubuntu.net](http://lubuntu.net/)