# Cannot install zRam

Tags: 10.04, installation, zram

I tried to install zRam using following commands in terminal -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/zram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
```

But it throws the following error which says that the package is not available,

```
E: Couldn't find package zramswap-enabler
```

I could not even find any repository with name `shnatsel/zram` or similar in my system.

As an alternative, i tried to install it from its `deb` file, which throws dependency error even though i have `kernel 2.6.38-13-generic` installed in my system.

Dependency Error:

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: linux (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-generic (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-generic (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-generic-pae (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-server (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-virtual (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-server (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-virtual (>= 2.6.37.1)
```

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: I presume you downloaded the i386 natty deb? also - the deb wont work with 64bit.  What are you using?  Add the dependency error when you attempt to install.

Comment: @fossfreedom Its ubuntu 10.04 32bit and here is the error -- Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: linux (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-generic (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-generic (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-generic-pae (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-server (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-virtual (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-server (>= 2.6.37.1)|linux-image-virtual (>= 2.6.37.1)

Comment: have you install the 2.6.38 headers?  - as an aside - welcome to AskUbuntu.  When replying to comments with extra information, remember to edit your original question.  Stuff like your comment is hard to read because its unformatted.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom yep i have installed it, n i appreciate your advice :D

Comment: open up synaptic and search for each of those dependencies - ensure they have the green "i'm installed" symbol.  Confirm that the version installed is greater than 2.6.37.1

Comment: could you also help in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82898/prerequisites-to-tweak-nautilus)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a compressed ramdisk (ramzswap)? Huge speed gain](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48732/how-to-use-a-compressed-ramdisk-ramzswap-huge-speed-gain)

Comment: is it necessary that i dedicate a seperate swap partition for zram to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ppa is for Ubuntu 11.04 / 11.10 (as you can see when you click on technical details).

That is also the reason for your dependency error when you try to install the `.deb` manually.

For Ubuntu 11.10+ versions, this is available in the official repositories as: `zram-config`. You just need to run `$ sudo apt install zram-config` to install it.

Comment: You are correct.  The ppa is only for 11.04/11.10

Answer (score 0):

For older versions: below are the exact steps as mentioned on its [official Launchpad  page](https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/zram).

> **On older (pre 9.10) Ubuntu systems**
>
> **Step 1:** Visit the PPA's overview page in Launchpad. Look for the heading that reads Adding this PPA to your system and click the
>   *Technical details about this PPA* link.
>
> **Step 2:** Use the *Display sources.list* entries drop-down box to select the version of Ubuntu you're using.
>
> **Step 3:** You'll see that the text-box directly below reads something like this:
>
> `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty
>   main
>   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main`
>
> Copy those lines.
>
> **Step 4:** Open a terminal and type:
>
> `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> This will open a text editor containing the list of archives that your
>   system is currently using. Scroll to the bottom of the file and paste
>   the lines you copied in the step above.
>
> Save the file and exit the text editor.
>
> **Step 5:** Back on the PPA's overview page, look for the *Signing key* heading. You'll see something like:
>
> `1024R/72D340A3 (What is this?)`
>
> Copy the portion after the slash but not including the help link; e.g.
>   just `72D340A3`.
>
> **Step 6:** Now you need to add that key to your system so Ubuntu can verify the packages from the PPA. In your terminal, enter:
>
> `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 72D340A3`
>
> Replace `72D340A3` with whatever you copied in the step 5.
>
> This will now pull down the PPA's key and add it to your system.
>
> **Step 7:** Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about,
>   including the PPA you just added:
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> Now you're ready to start installing software from the PPA!

Comment: there is no version for ubuntu 10.04 :(, thanx for your help though :D

Comment: [`gksu gedit ...` should be used instead of `sudo gedit ...`.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)